# Get items in a list that are greater than a selected item

Tags: c#, linq, compareto, icomparable

I have a list of `Versions`.

```
List<Version> versions = GetVersions();
```

And I have a `selectedVersion`.

My `Version` class implements `IComparable`.

```
public class Version : IComparable<Version>
```

So I can do `versions.Sort()`. At this point my `Version` objects are sorted in the list let's say by the `Name` property.

From the list of `Versions`, I would like to get items that are higher than my `selectedVersion`. How can I do that with Linq?

What I have tried is casting the `selectedVersion` to `IComparable` and then using `CompareTo` but I get an `InvalidCastException` error.

```
IComparable comparable = (IComparable)selectedVersion;
if(comparable.CompareTo(selectedVersion)) > 0
```

Comment: Why do you cast to an `IComparable` when Version only implements `IComparable<Version>`?

Comment: IComparable is a method for comparing objects while selectedVersion is a type Version.

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga noted. I should be casting to `IComparable<Version>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way is to use [`Comparer<T>.Default`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azhsac5f(v=vs.110).aspx) which will work as soon as the type `T` implements either `IComparable<T>` or `IComparable`:

```
var result = versions
    .Where(version => Comparer<Version>.Default.Compare(version, selectedVersion) > 0)
    .ToList();
```

You can even encapsulate it in a custom extension method (so you [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> GreaterThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T value, IComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        if (comparer == null) comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        return source.Where(item => comparer.Compare(item, value) > 0);
    }
}
```

and use simply

```
var result = versions.GreaterThan(selectedVersion).ToList();
```

Comment: Workaround? He-he, that's what `OrderBy`, `Min`, `Max` internally is using when you don't specify explicit comparer, so I guess they consider this to be a solution :)

Comment: So it still does rely on my `CompareTo` implementation?

Comment: Absolutely. You can put a breakpoint and see. It's just an universal method, so you don't have to think what exact interface is implemented by the class.

Comment: this is a more generic solution then :)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have implemented `IComparable<T>` which is not the same as `IComparable`. Either implement `IComparable` as well or cast to `IComparable<Version>` and you should be able to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
versions.Where(x => x.CompareTo(selectedVersion) > 0).ToList();
```

or if `IComparable<Version>` is implemented explicit:

```
versions.Where(x => (x as IComparable<Version>).CompareTo(selectedVersion) > 0).ToList();
```